# Possible to enable libc++ debug checks?

Tags: c++, libc++

I've been wondering if it is possible to enable any debug checks for libc++. One of my favorite things about MSVC's STL is that it catches some otherwise hard to find bugs right from the get go (though I wish it were easier to disable for speed).  After peeking in the headers I tried:

```
#define _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL 2
```

However, this leads to build errors ('__get_db undeclared').  Any insights on whether this is a work in progress, or if there is a different expected way to enable these checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a work in progress.
There's a (very old) status page [here](http://libcxx.llvm.org/debug_mode.html) that I need to update.

The idea is that users will interact with it by setting the preprocessor symbol `_LIBCPP_DEBUG`
Just defining it will give basic tests, setting it to a number > 1 will give more extensive tests.

However, as you have found, it is currently non-functional.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll keep a look out on that page.  It is a shame we can't make use of the debugging features you've already managed, but I understand that the task isn't as simple as what it appears at face value.  I will say however that one of the main reasons I own a PC at this point is to get those extra debug checks out of the VC compiler (I still do most development on a mac).

Answer (score 1):

It appears some progress was made on this in the meantime. At least there is some [documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html) now that doesn't state that the debug mode is horribly broken.

As stated in the docs I link, the debug mode shall be controlled by defining `_LIBCPP_DEBUG` to either 0 or 1; the macro `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL` appears to be some internal switch.

However, looking at question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50079172/3002139), spurious compilation errors can and do still happen.