# Swap between at() and operator[] for std::vector depending on compile switch/NDEBUG

Tags: c++, clang++

I know that g++ (and MSVC) have switches that allow bounds checking on operator[] , unfortunately, to my knowledge, LLVM's libc++ doesn't have a complete implementation of such switches or debug code.

On my current project I have been using my own implementation of vector (that I wrote for portability a few years back) which doesn't throw exceptions and has assert based bounds checking on operator[] and at (in fact one calls the other and they behave identically as there are no exceptions).

I'm going to be handing over this code-base after I've finished my current program and it may be in use for a long time. Since I'm not supposed to be required to maintain it or anything I would rather be fully standard compliant everywhere and I don't feel that re-implementing a container is in the spirit of the standard, (I also highly doubt that my container is as good as one written by the libc++ or libstdc++ team).

Is there some preprocessor magic or similar that I can do to make operator[] behave like at() during debug (so it aborts due to an uncaught exception) and behave like operator[] when I disable this debug mode?
(Project is fully C++14 supported)

Comment: You wrote a non-standard reinvention of a standard container for ... _portability_?

Comment: `assert(i < vector.size()); auto x = vector[i]; /* etc */`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: one quite famous C++ author/speaker I used to work with locked himself and his team away for a couple years writing their own containers claiming the commercial compiler versions were too buggy and varied - by the time he finished (about 10 years ago), all the major compiler vendors had good libraries and nobody wanted to use his.  Still - such things had their day (somewhat earlier than that)....

Comment: One half-way reasonable option is to change "your vector" so it wraps a `std::vector` - using its implementation - while customising `operator[]` to call the `vector`'s `at()` in debug builds.  That still means having a name other than `std::vector` hanging around, which isn't ideal....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It wasn't for portability per se, we had a Variant type and needed sizeof(Vector) to be the same on all platforms, that requirement isn't in the project, but we continued to use our containers until I realised that long-term that could be a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can see from [the trunk libc++ source code for vector](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/vector) that there is indeed such a check inside `std::vector<>::operator[]`, which goes through `_LIBCPP_ASSERT`.

Unfortunately, [the libc++ debug feature is not yet functional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23848666/560648).

So:

- Watch for libc++ updates
- Train your team to *expect* `operator[]` to silently accept broken input. That's what it does, by definition. Coming to rely on implementation-specific additional sanity checks is *a really bad idea*. Your team should be writing their own asserts if they're not sure what they're doing.

Comment: This is probably the only sensible answer, but the code also will be used and modified by inexperienced C++ "non-developers" and I'm trying to provide as easy a set of interfaces as possible (such as a core that instantiates the required core classes behind the scenes) and it would be nice to have a way of avoiding them blowing up the code on their own. (None of them will think to use .at or even know it exists, and I find it massively decreases code readability). I'll happily accept this if no-one has a possibly hack fix that "resolves" the problem.

Comment: @Goobley: Yeah at some point you have to train rather than protect. :) Your code review practices should account for this. I understand the desire but I (a) really do think you're creating an environment wherein inexperienced folk develop a false sense of security [very dangerous!!], and (b) indeed cannot think of anything else you can do.

Comment: This seems the voice of reason to me (when I push my prejudices out of the way), I'll make notes about using an assert if they feel that one could be necessary, it's just a big jump for the astronomers very set on IDL and python who are getting me to build something faster.

Comment: @Goobley Nature of the beast I think

Answer (score -1):

> Is there some preprocessor magic or similar that I can do to make operator[] behave like at() during debug (so it aborts due to an uncaught exception) and behave like operator[] when I disable this debug mode? (Project is fully C++14 supported)

Uhhh ... how about this?

```
const T& your_vector::operator[](std::size_t index) const
{
#ifndef NDEBUG // !! double negative condition
    if(index >= size_) // assume size_ is std::size_t size_; member of class
        throw std::out_of_bounds{"const T& your_vector::operator[]"};
#endif
    return data_[index]; // assume data_ is a native array containing the elements
}

const T& your_vector::at(std::size_t index) const
{
    if(index >= size_) // assume size_ is std::size_t size_; member of class
        throw std::out_of_bounds{"const T& your_vector::at"};
    return data_[index]; // assume data_ is a native array containing the elements
}
```

The indexing operator implementation is identical to `at` when DEBUG is defined and faster when the macro is not defined.

Comment: This is very much what our current Vector does, however for long-term maintainability (this is scientific code that may be modified by "non-programmers" in the future, I want to stick as close to the standard library as possibly, especially not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: OP is asking how to get libc++'s `std::vector<>` impl to do this.